# Android studio very simple Drum Machine

Tags: android

I'm trying to do a very basic step sequencer drum Machine. My app only has 2 Image Buttons (play and stop) and 4 toggle button. The goal of the app is that when i press the play button, the app plays a snare sound for each toggle button that is on but not all at once, only one after another (like a kind of step sequencer) and keeps playing the sounds on a loop until i press the stop button.

So far here is what i've coded

```
public class Sampler {

    SoundPool sp;
    private int snareId;
    private Context mycontext;
    public boolean playing;
    public ToggleButton button1, button2, button3, button4;
    public ImageButton playButton, stopButton;



    public Sampler(Context appcontext) {

        this.mycontext = appcontext;

        sp = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

        snareId = sp.load(mycontext, R.raw.snare, 1);


    }

    public void play() {
        if (playButton.isPressed()) {
            playing = true;
        }
        while (playing == true) {
            if (button1.isChecked()) {
                sp.play(snareId, 10, 10, 1, 0, 1);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(60000 / (120 * 4));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (button2.isChecked()) {
                    sp.play(snareId, 10, 10, 1, 0, 1);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(60000 / (120 * 4));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (button3.isChecked()) {
                        sp.play(snareId, 10, 10, 1, 0, 1);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(60000 / (120 * 4));
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (button4.isChecked()) {
                            sp.play(snareId, 10, 10, 1, 0, 1);
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(60000 / (120 * 4));
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            if(playing ==false){
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void stop(){
        if (stopButton.isPressed()) {
            playing = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, when i run the app, pressing the play or stop button will make my app crash and quit and i don't know why. I also have a main activity code very basic

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ToggleButton button1, button2, button3, button4;
    public Sampler mySample;
    public ImageButton playButton;
    public ImageButton stopButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        playButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
        stopButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.stop);

        button1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button4 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.button4);

    }

    public void playSeq() {
        mySample.play();
    }

    public void stopSeq() {
        mySample.stop();
    }
}
```

So i would like to know where my mistake is and why my app doesn't seem to work. Thank you all.

Comment: what does the stacktrace say?

Comment: it says :"Could not find method playSeq(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton with id 'play'"
Does that mean my path to the play button is wrong or that my method is wrong?

Comment: means that `public void playSeq()` needs to be changed to `public void playSeq(View v)` for example. probably also needs to be added to `stopSeq()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately i tried to change as you said but it still crashes but now with a new error on the stacktrace :"Could not execute method for android:onClick"